# Scrolling div on body with overflow:hidden property

Tags: html, css

I've trying to have a bouncing div on top of a static body. The body of the page needs to have the overflow:hidden property.

With that the property the background image stays static all the time, but I want to create a centered div that can move like it has the property overflow:auto.

Like, when you are at the top of the page and you keep scrolling, the page goes down slightly.

I created a centered div that allows scrolling on top of the static body, but I can't find the way to create the effect of the page going down.

Code is here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bgja1c2v/

And here:

```css
body{
  background-color: lightgrey;
  background-image: url('../img/mapD.svg');
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position: left top;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.c1{
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.c2{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you expound a bit more about what you're looking for? I'm not quite getting it yet. Maybe show an example of something similar to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: *Like, when you are at the top of the page and you keep scrolling, the page goes down slightly.* Are you talking about a bouncing scroll? https://vimeo.com/43531216

Comment: Yes, That's the effect the video shows what I wanted to add to content    
(div c2) of the page, keeping the body static. Sorry for my poor description of the effect